# Does NSURLSession persist?

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsurlsession

My commercial internet server (which allows 600 concurrent connections) seems to become rapidly overwhelmed when 15-20 folks run my app at the same time.  The app makes use of NSURLSession to perform a lot of tasks, but the very first thing it does is go into a password protected portion of the server to retrieve a simple text file that contains the password to allow the user to proceed further in the app.

Once past the password screen the app functions primarily as a .pdf viewer, again making use of NSURLSession to download and display various files as selected by the user.

In testing the app with 6-8 users running the app simultaneously it performs flawlessly.  The issue begins as more users run the app simultaneously.

My question is how NSURLSession connects, or more importantly "disconnects" from my server.

My app makes use of a tab controller to display various View Controllers that each present a list of files available to view.  Each of those in turn load another View Controller to display the file selected.  Each view controller in the app creates a NSURLSession with the following code in the ViewDidLoad method:

```
   NSURLSessionConfiguration *sessionConfig = [NSURLSessionConfiguration defaultSessionConfiguration];
   sessionConfig.allowsCellularAccess = YES;
   sessionConfig.timeoutIntervalForRequest = 30;
   sessionConfig.timeoutIntervalForResource = 60;
   sessionConfig.HTTPMaximumConnectionsPerHost = 150;
   sessionConfig.URLCache = NULL;

   //Create the session with the newly created sessionConfig.
   session = [NSURLSession sessionWithConfiguration:sessionConfig delegate:self delegateQueue:nil];
```

I then use the newly created session to create a downloadTask to pull down the selected file.  Is it possible that each of these sessions stays connected to the server for the life of the app?

The ViewControllers are all modal, so my assumption was that when a new ViewController is loaded, and creates another session, that the newly created session would then terminate when the ViewController is dismissed.  I am no longer convinced that assumption is valid.

Should I create a single instance of a NSURLSession (in the app delegate maybe) and then reference that single instance from each view controller?  Seems like that is the way to go, but there are a lot of view controllers I will need to rewrite, and wanted to ask here first.

If each session stays live for the run of the app I guess I am potentially creating 100's of concurrent session with a single instance of the app...awesome.

Thanks for the help!

Comment: And I just realized that I fat fingered a 0 into the HTTPMaximumConnectionsPerHost line.  That was supposed to be 15, so maybe that is the culprit as well.

Comment: So what I am going to try is to use the viewWillDisappear method in each viewController to run the method [session invalidateAndCancel] and I also set sessionConfig.HTTPMaximumConnectionsPerHost = 1 in each view controller as well.  I am hoping this truly limits the app to one connection to the server at a time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

NSURLSession was created to make it easier to apply the same settings to http connections.

Chances are good that you can just use `[NSURLSession sharedSession]` without modification.  (Modifications might include an ephemeral session so that no data is cached, or a session that adds the same header data to every request.  Take a look at NSURLSessionConfiguration for more details.)

Back to your original question though, NSURLSession does not open a network connection.  There is no downside to keeping one around.  You could keep one for your entire application instead of creating a similar one for each UIViewController.

When you create a `NSURLSessionTask` (or one of its subclasses) and then call `resume` on that object a network connection is created.  Those are the objects you need to be careful about.  Once you start it, it will run in the background until it finishes or fails.  Exiting the current UIViewController will not kill it.

One think you might do is to keep a NSULRSession per UIViewController and then add something like the following.  That will kill any pending downloads when you navigate away from the current page.

```
- (void)viewWillDisappear:(BOOL)animated {
    [super viewWillDisappear:animated];
    [session invalidateAndCancel];
}
```

Another thing to try would be to add a timeout to the NSURLSessionConfiguration object.

```
config.timeoutIntervalForRequest = 5;
config.timeoutIntervalForResource = 120;
```

The first will stop any request after it has been 5 seconds from the last piece of data received and the second puts a 2 minute timeout on the entire request.  Play with values and see if they make it any better.

Comment: In my last comment I mentioned that I was going to park a [session invalidateAndCancel] call in the viewWillDisappear method, but never came back to discuss the results.  So I am giving you credit for the answer, and thanks for such a complete and easy to understand answer!  The end result was that doing this did help, but in the end I had to upgrade the server to Virtual Private Server from the economy hosting plan to handle the concurrent user load.  Thanks again for the great response!